# Parse a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string like following string

```
{
    FlightId : 1,
    [
        {
            AirplaneId : 1
        },
        {
            AirplaneId : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have defined 2 classes to convert this JSON string to the objects of these 2 classes :

```
class Airplane
{
    int AirplaneId;
}

class Flight
{
    int FlightId;
    List<Airplane> Airplanes;
}
```

During convert the string to these classes objects I get an error. The error tells me that JSON string is not recognized and I should define a name for the list in my JSON string. I can not change the JSON string , how to define my class to convert this JSON String

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us the code you're using to deserialize the JSON string, along with the precise error message?

Comment: *"I have a JSON string like following..."* No, you don't. You have something that *looks like* JSON, but isn't. Thus, you cannot use a JSON deserializer to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you get an error since that is not a valid JSON.

In order to make it valid, you need to have a key to match your list value:

```
{
    "FlightId" : 1,
    "Airplanes": [
        {
            "AirplaneId" : 1
        },
        {
            "AirplaneId" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, you need to wrap your key values in quotes.

You can use https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ in the future to make sure your JSON strings are valid.

Comment: I talk to my JSON String provider service and they believe they gave me a standard JSON string. What do you think ?!

Comment: @AliForoughi I think either they are wrong and they don't know what JSON is, or that you pasted a non string by accident (ordered descending by likelihood).

Comment: @AliForoughi if you are sure, you don't make any copy paste errors, send them a JSON specification. That's all

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your array, you need to define a key for it, like:

```
{
    "FlightId" : 1,
    "Airplanes": [
        {
            "AirplaneId" : 1
        },
        {
            "AirplaneId" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

`Airplanes` must be a list in your class later.

JSON is a "Key-Value" based format, so every value (even arrays) needs a key.